# Laravel Email validation rules fail only on live server. Possible causes?

Tags: laravel, validation

I run a customer order input through a simple form validation.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class CreateOrderWebstoreRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    { 
        // Use additional Address valudation rules if Order is not picked up
        // dd('debugging halt',request());

        $address_rules = [];
        if (! request()->is_pickup) {
            $address_rules = [
                'street' => 'required|min:3|max:100',
                'house_number' => 'required|numeric|max:100000',
                'house_number_suffix' => 'nullable|max:10',
                'postal_code' => 'required|max:10',
                'town' => 'required|min:3|max:50',
                'country' => 'required|min:2|max:2',
                'region' => 'nullable|min:3|max:50',
                'owner' => 'nullable|min:3|max:25',
            ];
        }

        return array_merge([
            'first_name' => 'required|min:3|max:50',
            'middle_name' => 'nullable|min:1|max:15',
            'last_name' => 'required|min:3|max:50',
            'company_name' => 'nullable|min:3|max:50',
            'email_address' => 'required|email:rfc,dns|max:50',
            'telephone_number' => 'nullable|min:10|max:25',
            'description' => 'nullable|min:5|max:250',
        ], $address_rules);
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            
        ];
    }
}
```

The weird thing this has been working without customer having errors for months. But in de last week or so we suddenly got multiple customers complaining that the validation of their email failed (the first 'rule' that triggers the 'email' response from validation.php

The problem is that testing this on a local host we can't reproduce this, only on the live server.

The host is a shared host, dedicated for Laravel apps, currently running Laravel 6.18.15 and PHP 7.4.16. Local is running running Laravel 6.18.10 and PHP 7.4.2 We had some problems before where the host failed to update PHP, but that doesn't seem to be the case here (if even possible)

The problem is that I don't really know how to fix this or even circumvent it. Changing the email validation to
 `'email' => 'required|regex:/(.+)@(.+)\.(.+)/i'`
is giving me an 'IDN Conversion Failed' error.

Comment: Honestly I didn't got the whole thing, but at least I'd can suggest you to try something like 'regex:/^[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]{4,50}\@[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]{2,20}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/' instead of 'email' => 'required|regex:/(.+)@(.+)\.(.+)/i'

Comment: Apperently there is a problem with Guzzler that's causing this IDN Conversion Failed when the the above sends an email through Mailgun. I'm trying to solve that now first. But updating Laravel from 6.18 to the latest version is giving me trouble.